# how can I remove navbar?

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used azure login in asp.net core , when logout from project , its going on sign in  page where  get navbar  shown in image.
how can I remove navbar

```
<div class='page-topbar @ViewData["pagetopbar_class"]'>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:white;">
.
.
.
.
         @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                   {
                      ...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       ...
                    }
               </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add if clause to your code As you used for sign out:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item active pl-5">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class='page-topbar @ViewData["pagetopbar_class"]'>
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:white;">
    .
    .
    .
    .
         @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                   {
                      ...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       ...
                    }
               </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
   }
</div>
```